# Date format change angular 2

Tags: angular, date, date-formatting

I need to change my date format, the problem is that I can't use moment.js, I need just to transform date from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy.
I use angular v 2.4.0.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `DatePipe` [pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

```
date_expression | date[:format]
```

in your case

```
{{ date_expression | date:'dd-MM-yy' }}
```

How to use the pipe inside the **component** :

```
NgModule({
  ....
  providers: [DatePipe]
})
```

or

```
@Component({
   ....
  providers: [DatePipe]
})
```

In you component set it as a `date` variable

```
constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.date = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'dd-MM-yy');
}
```

Comment: Ye, it look very easy, but is it possible to put this {{ date_expression | date:'dd-MM-yy' }} into variable(I need to put it on class later) I mean variable= {{ date_expression | date:'dd-MM-yy' }}

Answer (score 5):

You can do it creating custom Pipe. Refer below code. For more info refer [DatePipe Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe).

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
    name: 'customDateFormat',
})
export class customDateFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string) {
       var datePipe = new DatePipe("en-US");
        value = datePipe.transform(value, 'dd-mm-yyyy');
        return value;
    }
}
```

Add custom pipe in html as shown below:

```
{{currentDate | customDateFormat }}
```

Comment: Ye, it look very easy, but is it possible to put this {{ date_expression | date:'dd-MM-yy' }} into variable(I need to put it on class later) I mean variable= {{ date_expression | date:'dd-MM-yy' }}

Comment: @JędrekMarkowski  : But if you want to use any library in future like momentJS or others. You have to modify in one place to get effect on all pages. Any ways you get a solution. :-)

Comment: its throwing error customDateFormat could not be found

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a function like this

```
function formatDate() {
    let addZeroToLoneFigure = (n) => n.toString().length === 1 ? '0' + n : n.toString();
    let format = 'DD-MM-YYYY';
    let d= new Date();
    format.replace('DD', addZeroToLoneFigure(d.getDate()));
    format.replace('MM', addZeroToLoneFigure(d.getMonth() + 1));
    format.replace('YYYY', addZeroToLoneFigure(d.getFullYear()));
    return format;
}
```

Comment: Ye, it look very easy, but is it possible to put this {{ date_expression | date:'dd-MM-yy' }} into variable(I need to put it on class later) I mean variable= {{ date_expression | date:'dd-MM-yy' }}

Comment: I didn't get what you want, but my function returns something, so just do `let myVar = this.formatDate();`