# change date input to arabic and set default value

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

how can I make this date input as this ?? (arabic) from tight to left and arrow in the left side , with this default value .

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date format change angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844861/date-format-change-angular-2)

Answer (score 2):

you need to set 'direction' properties of your element to 'rtl' (right to left)  .I've used Bootstrap for dropdown. please follow below link for more info on how to use Bootstrap dropdown.
http://bootstrap.rtlcss.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

```css
.rtl{direction:rtl}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rtlcss.com/bootstrap/v4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-P4uhUIGk/q1gaD/NdgkBIl3a6QywJjlsFJFk7SPRdruoGddvRVSwv5qFnvZ73cpz" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rtlcss.com/bootstrap/v4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-54+cucJ4QbVb99v8dcttx/0JRx4FHMmhOWi4W+xrXpKcsKQodCBwAvu3xxkZAwsH" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="dropdown show">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle rtl" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
  </a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```