# Angular 4+ - How to fetch date from input datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker

I'm new to angular.

I have an input date picker. I want to get/fetch the date selected in the date picker.

Code: Html file:

```
 <input class="form-control m-input " id="m_datepicker_2_validate" placeholder="Select Date" readonly="" type="text">
```

I'm trying to console.log the selected date.
In the component.ts file I've added a variable `staff_date_booking : Date;`
and created a function

```
bookStaffEmployeeDate(){
        console.log("This is the DATE:", this.staff_book_date);
    }
```

and in the html I've added

```
 <input [ngModel]="staff_book_date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" class="form-control m-input " id="m_datepicker_2_validate" placeholder="Select Date" readonly="" type="text">
```

Once the date is selected I'm calling this function on (click) but I'm getting this.staff_book_date as undefined.

**How can I store the selected date in a variable like staff_book_date**

Comment: try changing `[ngModel]` to `[(ngModel)]` in your input tag.

Comment: Did that, still getting undefined.

Comment: maybe you are calling bookStaffEmployeeDate() before the value of staff_book_date is selected

Comment: No, it is after the date is selected. There's another input after the date picker and on its click I've called the function.

Comment: try https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vbukxm?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

Don't use pipes inside `ngModel`.
Also, use the two-way binding in the `ngModel`

```
<input [(ngModel)]="staff_book_date"
```

Comment: Removed pipes and added two way binding in ngModel, still it says undefined.

Comment: No console errors after removing pipes. Console output:
This is the DATE: undefined

Comment: where do you call the bookStaffEmployeeDate methos

Comment: There is another input field right after the date picker I've added
(click)="bookStaffEmployeeDate()" on the input field.

Answer (score 1):

Create a property in your **.ts** file and make a two way binding with it in your **.html**

Make the following changes

**.component.ts**

```
staff_book_date : any;

bookStaffEmployeeDate(){
        console.log("This is the DATE:", this.staff_book_date);
}
```

**component.html**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="staff_book_date" class="form-control m-input " id="m_datepicker_2_validate" placeholder="Select Date" type="date">
<button (click)="bookStaffEmployeeDate()">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: If I try to create a 2 way binding model it gives an error regarding the pipes.
Error I get in console log:
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 19 in [staff_book_date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'=$event] in ng:///ServiceModule/ServicesComponent.html@809:40 ("<div class="input-group date">

Comment: Remove the pipe in two way binding.

Comment: if you want to format your input using pipe, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44844932/7812112)

Comment: After removal of pipe I get no error but the console log shows date as undefined.
Console log:

This is the DATE: undefined

Comment: if you are not entering any value in input box, it will be undefined since we have declared `staff_book_date ` not defined it. Also, you have made your input as readonly, you wont be able to edit it also.

Comment: How do I give it the value of date selected?

Comment: you can use `type='date'` instead of `type='text'`, and remove readonly so user can change the date.

Comment: Done. Still says undefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182466/discussion-between-sarthak-aggarwal-and-string-name).