# Angular 5 datepicker incorrect value

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-directive

I'm using [ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker) in an Angular 5 project, but I'm having issues with the value when I use it to select year only.

I select the year and the value displays correctly in the input, but other value is shown when I display the value from formBuilder.get:

[image]

I need only the year to send to my API. How to solve this?

My Input:

```
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error' : hasError('modelYear', 'vehicle')}">
    <label>Ano {{ createRemovalForm.get('vehicle.modelYear').value }}</label>
    <input type="text" a2e-datetimepicker [options]="{locale: 'pt-br', format: 'YYYY'}" class="form-control dt-placeholder" placeholder="Ano" formControlName="modelYear">
</div>
```

FormBuilder:

```
this.createRemovalForm = this.fb.group({
    idAuction: ['', Validators.required],
    idRemovalType: ['', Validators.required],
    addressRemLat: ['', Validators.required],
    addressRemLng: ['', Validators.required],
    addressRemShort: ['', Validators.required],
    addressRemLong: ['', Validators.required],
    addressRemCity: ['', Validators.required],
    financedInsuredName: ['', Validators.required],
    bankInsurerName: ['', Validators.required],
    contract: ['', Validators.required],
    acessory: ['', Validators.required],
    scheduled: [true, Validators.required],
    dtToRemove: ['', Validators.required],
    contactName: ['', Validators.required],
    contactPhone: ['', Validators.required],
    vehicle: this.fb.group({
        idRequestVehicleType: ['', Validators.required],
        manufacturer: ['', Validators.required],
        model: ['', Validators.required],
        color: ['', Validators.required],
        modelYear: ['', Validators.required],
        plate: ['', Validators.required],
        chassis: ['', Validators.required],
        observation: [],
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you check with passing option like -

options = {
    format: "YYYY",
};

check here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker

Comment: I'm using this in [options] in the input

Comment: Input field showing Year only but you are not getting same in form control - modelYear ?

Comment: Exactly this! The problem is in the value in the form control. The input field is ok!

Comment: ok, you can use pipe inside the component to format date before sending to api like - this.formName.value.modelYear = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(this.formName.value.modelYear), 'YYYY'); look at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844861/date-format-change-angular-2?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Solved! Thank you!