# Convert an ISO date to DD:MM:YYYY HH:MM in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have my date in entry :

```
2022-11-21T21:07:56.830-07:00
```

And I would like to transform it like that:

```
21/11/2022 07:56
```

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44844932/4632239

Comment: You can use https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe or  https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate

Comment: To confirm, the original item is a string, not a Date, right? (data type, that is.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third-party library like [dayjs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format) to format dates

In your case, you would need to do

```
dayjs('2022-11-21T21:07:56.830-07:00').format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm')
```

Although your input doesn't seem like an ISO date, indeed in console

```
new Date('2022-11-21T21:07:56.830-07:00')
Tue Nov 22 2022 05:07:56 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

So the output would be (for DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm)

```
22/11/2022 05:07
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this https://www.npmjs.com/package/user-timezone npm package to convert dates into any specific format.